# Delete folders using os.scandir recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, delete-file

I'm trying to delete folders recursively using os.scandir() something like this

```
rootdir = '/automation/major/build/testing'
def list_and_delete_dirs(rootdir):
   for dir in os.scandir(rootdir):
       if dir.is_dir():
          directory_path = dir.path
          if os.path.exists(directory_path):
             cmd = (f"sudo rm -rf {directory_path}")
             subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
       list_and_delete_dirs(dir)
```

But it's deleting only the first occurrence for example if there are 5 folders  A B C D E, after the first deletion it's throwing this error

```
ERROR:root:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/build/testing/A'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "utils/delta_automation/utils/cleanup/deleteOldBuilds.py", line 53, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "utils/delta_automation/utils/cleanup/deleteOldBuilds.py", line 39, in main
    list_and_delete_dirs(rootdir)
  File "utils/delta_automation/utils/cleanup/deleteOldBuilds.py", line 32, in list_and_delete_dirs
    list_and_delete_dirs(dir)
  File "utils/delta_automation/utils/cleanup/deleteOldBuilds.py", line 14, in list_and_delete_dirs
    for dir in os.scandir(rootdir):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'build/testing/A'
```

It's successfully deleting folder A but not able to go to the next directory, how to fix the code?

Comment: You are deleting `A` and then calling `list_and_delete_dirs(dir)` for A which no longer exists, thus scandir fails on recursive call.

Comment: scandir return only the filename so before using it you need to add the name of directory you are scanning. There are also Python function to delete files and directory, no need for a sub process. Also, try to not use the same name for global variable and function argument, variables. Could lead to confusion and errors.